# Visual Studio: differentiate app.config for debug and release mode

Tags: visual-studio, app-config, production-environment

Is there a way to automatically use a separate app.config when building in release mode?

In other words, I want to test with one app.config, and release with another.

Currently, I keep a separate copy called app.config.production, and manually overwrite bin\Release\Application.exe.config after building for release.

Answer (score 54):

Unload the project in Solution Explorer via the context menu.

Edit the `.csproj` file via the context menu and add this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppConfig>App.$(Configuration).config</AppConfig>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: although intellisense does not show appconfig as a valid property. It's works. I think it is most useful in the final stage of development, when no more major changes are needed in the app.config file. thanks

Comment: This even works with .NET 7. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21):

A clean solution is to group 2 files `App.Debug.config` and `App.Release.config` into `App.config` and change the good file into `App.config` depending on the configuration at compile time:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="App.Debug.config">
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.Release.config">
        <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="SetAppConfig" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Copy SourceFiles="App.Debug.config" DestinationFiles="App.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " />
    <Copy SourceFiles="App.Release.config" DestinationFiles="App.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " />
</Target>
```

With this solution you will get something like this in Visual Studio:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: But this solution just overrides App.config with either debug or release version, if you shared settings for both you will still have to maintain them in both configs so that it does not gets removed.

Comment: Depending on your build target it will copy `App.config` to `YourProject.exe.config` before this target runs. So in this case it's better to use `BeforeTargets="Compile;_CopyAppConfigFile"`

Answer (score 20):

I have recently posted a supremely belated response to a similar SO topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546685/2798367

I will repeat it here for clarity:

This is somewhat late to the party, but I stumbled upon a nice way of implementing the `web.transform` approach for `app.config` files. (i.e. it makes use of the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform`)

**I think it is "nice" because it is a pure xml approach and doesn't require 3rd party software.**

A parent / default App.config file is descended from, according to your various build configurations.
These descendants then only override what they need to.
In my opinion this is much more sophisticated and robust than having to maintain `x` number of config files which get copied in their entirety, such as in other answers.

A walkthrough has been posted here: http://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/

---

Look, Mom - No explicit post-build events in my IDE!

Comment: For VS 2017, `v10.0` has to be replaced with `v15.0` in `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />` in the walk-through above.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio 2022 with a .net 6 web api, this solution did not work.

Comment: `v10.0` should be replaced with `v$(VisualStudioVersion)` to make this solution compatible with any VS version

Answer (score 10):

A simple and fast way is to create a second file "App.release.config" and insert this pre-build event:

```
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)App.config" "$(ProjectDir)App.debug.config"
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)App.release.config" "$(ProjectDir)App.config"
```

And this post build event:

```
IF $(ConfigurationName) == Release COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)App.debug.config" "$(ProjectDir)App.config"
```

This might be a bit odd, but it will allow you to keep using the `.Settings` files as debug settings, that are still linked to the `App.config`. The `App.release.config` must be build by hand, but it's pretty easy to switch this functionality.

Comment: where do you add these build events?

Comment: @Adrian Right click your project in your solution, click on "Properties" and open the tap "Build Events"

Comment: I really like this, simple and effective and doesnt rely on msbuild magic which tends to change over time.

Answer (score 10):

I highly recommend SlowCheetah for app.config transformations. Visit this nuget gem here [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/)

Comment: Side Note: SlowCheetah only works when you publish your works, not when debugging.

Comment: that is no longer the case

Comment: Nice! I was hoping that change would come down the pike soon.

Comment: SlowCheetah is a much better solution than Pre build / Post build scripting.

Comment: VS 2022 Support too!  https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms-VS2022&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score 5):

Similar to top answer but with this approach you can see the actual file if preferred and intellisense doesn't complain in csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="SetAppConfig" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <Copy SourceFiles="debug.config" DestinationFiles="app.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " />
    <Copy SourceFiles="release.config" DestinationFiles="app.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' " />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, but app.config will recognise the standard MSBUILD substitution strings such as $(Configuration).