# VS2013 : Publish not using web.config transformations from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Here is the problem I'm having...

First off - everything works fine if I manually publish from the VS2013 IDE.

However, the solution has 3 publishable projects, so you have to do each one separately, and inevitably someone makes a mistake, and one of the projects that wasn't touched for this update doesn't get published, and so stuff is missing, bad things happen, etc.

So to eliminate human error, I'm creating a script to publish.

After researching various things ( especially on this site ), I've tried the following:

```
msbuild C:\Development\Isis\Isis.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ProdXport /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True
```

I've also tried it as:

```
msbuild C:\Development\Isis\Isis.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=ProdXport;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True
```

which also doesn't work...

And when I say doesn't work, it doesn't do the web.config transformation that the IDE publish does.

Now what I find odd as well is when I do it through the IDE, the Web.config file that is created has the same datetime stamp as all the other files ( as it was just created ).  However, when I do it via the command line, the time portion of the stamp for the Web.config file is 12:38 PM (Nor is that the time on any of the web.config tranform files).  No matter when I do this ( not a detailed example, but I ran the file creating at 4:20 PM, and it said 12:38 PM... ran it again at 4:42 PM, and it said 12:38 PM )

I've seen lots of examples for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 - but nothing explicit to 2013, and while I wouldn't have thought there was that big of a difference, none of the stuff I've seen from those examples is working for me...

Hopefully someone else has come across this and figured out what I'm doing wrong/different!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090311/different-application-settings-depending-on-configuration-mode/27546685#27546685

Comment: Not really.  It is a web.config that I need done - and its working fine when I do it from the IDE.  Trying to find a command line option that works so I can create a batch/script file to automate the process for all of the projects involved.