# Can't use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I built a Web Forms website using VS2015 where I user `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`
so that I can grammatically go through the files in my project.
When using VS2017 I get this error:

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The imported
>   project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\MyUser\Source\Workspaces\MyProject
>   TFVC2\Gemstar\MyProject.csproj'

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

Project project = new Project();
if (ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(mPath + "MyProject.csproj").Count == 0)
{
    project = new Project(mPath + "MyProject.csproj");
}
else
{
    project = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(mPath + "MyProject.csproj").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I want to mention that I installed BuildTools for VS2017 from https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Comment: Did you confirm the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file exists on disk?

Comment: Yes. In fact it works fine vs 2015

Comment: @boruchsiper, `When using VS2017 I get this error`--Have you installed VS2017 on your build server? If yes, why you installed build tools? Besides,  the import path for `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` should be incorrect. It  exists in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS - 
I resolved it by installing the latest version of Mono.

1. Installing Mono on macOS.
2. Search "omnisharp" in settings (command + ',').
3. Changed the setting **Omnisharp: Use Global Mono** to **always**.
4. Reload the vscode.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation in VS2017

It seems the old value of `MSBuildExtensionsPath32` set in the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`.

According to the error info:

> The imported project "**C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio**\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found.

The import path for `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` is not correct.

In the project file `.csproj`, we notice following import:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

So the value for `MSBuildExtensionsPath32` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` in the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`, which is not correct for Visual Studio 2017.

The value of `MSBuildExtensionsPath32` for Visual Studio 2017 should be:

BuildTool Installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0
```

Visual Studio Installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0
```

To resolve this issue, you could verride the value in your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildExtensionsPath32>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0</MSBuildExtensionsPath32>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

See the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077150/msbuild-15-webapplication-targets-is-missing) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension).