# Is Visual studio installation is required on the server where jenkins is installed?

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild

I am getting below error while building jenkins build for a .net project.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj(440,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

As It's trying to find the Visual studio folder on the server which is not present on the server. So is it mandatory to have the visual studio installed on the server?
Below is the complete error log I am getting in jenkins.

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/pure-nmittal/timesheet/src/master/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/pure-nmittal/timesheet/src/master/
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/pure-nmittal/timesheet/src/master/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 25e45ba269d04cb48a4d17090e391df08f73bedf (refs/remotes/origin/master)
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 25e45ba269d04cb48a4d17090e391df08f73bedf
Commit message: "profile"
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 25e45ba269d04cb48a4d17090e391df08f73bedf # timeout=10
[Timesheet_UAT] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins2437051443515371203.ps1'"
--Restoring Nuget packages BEGIN--
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
--Restoring Nuget packages END--
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=UAT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT
[Timesheet_UAT] $ cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=UAT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Active code page: 1252
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

-

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 11/27/2018 1:30:20 AM.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (1) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj(440,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (1) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1097,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj]
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj" (3) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (2:2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj(440,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
(GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1097,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj]


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj(440,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests\FleetPride.Timesheet.Tests.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj" (default target) (2:2) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Timesheet_UAT\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet\FleetPride.Timesheet.csproj(440,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    1 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.21
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: seems `The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found`

Comment: The Microsoft.WebApplications.targets is missing on the Jenkins server. This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing and similar issues. Have you tried installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools? There are relevant downloads available, but my link may be for wrong version of Visual Studio. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Thanks Sisve. I am able to make in work by creating the folder ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets") and copied the Microsoft.WebApplication.targets dll inside it.