# Azure devops build issue for .net projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I am trying to build a asp.net project on azure devops, it's giving me the below errors. But the same project is building locally in VS 2019 without any issue. In my project all the dll are updated

The imported project

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualS

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.227.2\test\1\s\Solution Code\Web Site\API\eCIL_DataLayer\eCIL_DataLayer.csproj]

I tried to build locally and its working fine. So it should work in Azure devops.

Comment: Is the agent for the build self-hosted or Microsoft-hosted? If self-hosted, was .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed on the agent's host?

Comment: If you are using self-hosted agent, please ensure the .NET Framework 4.7.2 installs successfully on your agent and the imported project exists in the Corresponding path.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its a self hosted agent .I have created the agent as the default agent not available. But just for the clarification, Do I need to update the server with NET Framework 4.7.2 patch where I have hosted the agent?

Comment: One more thing I have just checked that .NET framework 4.7.2 already installed on the server. Please let me know what to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found.

This [MSB3644](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3644?view=vs-2022) notes that `This error occurs when the .NET reference assemblies aren't found for the version of .NET that a project requests`.

Here are suggestions you can check:

1.Check that your project has a reference to the Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies NuGet package.

sample

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

2 If you are using `MSBuild` task in your azure pipeline, please remember to set `restoreNugetPackages` to  `True`.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **/*.sln'
  inputs:
    restoreNugetPackages: true
```

3 Check if the Reference assemblies for the version your project needs isn't present or appears to be corrupted, for example:

.NET 4.7.2 Framework reference assembly folders for should be under C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2

4 Please check if the `WebApplication.targets` exists on your machine.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"

Please check if `Web development build tools` on your self-hosted server.

Here is a similar ticket:

[MS-Build 2017 "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets " is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing/)

If there is any misunderstanding, please share your `.csproj` file and pipeline sample  to help us better understand your scenario.