# Inject IConfiguration to windows forms on .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, configuration, .net-6.0

I have class library called Persistence.EFCore contains this method

```
public static IServiceCollection AddPersistenceServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDbContext<SIMContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    return services;
}
```

and this is my code from Program.cs in winform project

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
         var builder = new HostBuilder()
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
         {
            builder.AddJsonFile("apsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<XtraMain>();
            services.AddPersistenceServices(Configuration);
            services.AddApplicationServices();
            services.AddTransient<FrmExpressionOfNeeds>();
            services.AddSingleton<IFormFactory, FormFactory>();

        });

    var host = builder.Build();
    using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        IServiceProvider services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
        XtraMain mainform = services.GetRequiredService<XtraMain>();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(mainform);
    }
}
```

I can't find a way to set the Configuration value.
The Configuration from IConfiguration supposed to get his value from

```
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

But in my case the

```
services.AddPersistenceServices(Configuration);
```

came before the build

Comment: You can edit the configuration file with notepad on any text editor.

Comment: I mean the Configuration from IConfiguration  it supposed to get his value from builder.Build() but in my case the services.AddPersistenceServices(Configuration); came before the build

Comment: You ask about setting the configuration.  You do not need to set in Program.  Most people just edit the config file.  You need to change : configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")

Comment: please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675178/9608194

Comment: The first parameter in `...ConfigureServices((hostContext, services)=>...` has a `Configuration` property. Use it like this: `services.AddPersistenceServices(hostContext.Configuration);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [ConfigureService((context, services)=>{ ... })](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder.configureservices?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is [HostBuilderContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which gives you access to configuration, using its [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#microsoft-extensions-hosting-hostbuildercontext-configuration) property.

So assuming you have a service extension method which accepts configuration, then you can easily pass configuration to it using `context.Configuration`.

**Example**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<Form1>());
    }
    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHelloServices(context.Configuration);
                services.AddTransient<Form1>();
            });
}
```

Comment: A useful link if you want to consider option patterns for your library in future:  [Options pattern guidance for .NET library authors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#iconfiguration-parameter)

Comment: Thank you very much it works, and thank you for the helpful link  .                                    
In this way, can I read the settings from anywhere in my application

Comment: You can of course share Configuration (like what I showed in my other answer). You can also configure and inject the Options<Something> anywhere you need that dependency.