# Can I use `IHostEnvironment` in Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I am trying to figure if there is way to add `appsettings.json` support to WindowsForms application, including adding environment related `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json` files on top, similar to what .NET Worker Service does in console application.

Main target is that I enable reading of `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable from multiple sources, without re-implementing it line by line.

.NET 6/7 Windows Forms project using `Main(...)` method to instantiate the application and manage it's lifetime and not `IHostEnvironment` like `WorkerService` or web app:

```cs
namespace WinFormsApp1;

internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
        // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

I've been able to add static `appsettings.json` support, without environments simply by using `ConfigurationBuilder` (independent from `HostEnvornment`).

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

    var configuration = builder.Build();
    var myConnection = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB");
    // ...
}
```

The problem is to add `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable that can be read from multiple sources, similar to what a [Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) does in Console app.

##### HostBuilder solutions

Majority "solution" I've found rely on `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(...)` method and subsequent `IHost.Run()` to start the app, which cannot be used to start WinForms app.

##### `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` solutions

Also, there is a category of solutions proposing to use `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` method from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` NuGet package, but that achieves completely different results (extends the `Configuration` object to read currently set environment variables, but does not extend `appsettings.json`).

Is there any way to configure and initialize `IHostEnvironment` object without actually using `IHost` to run the application?

UPDATE:
The linked answer provided in "duplicate question" link does too many things that are not necessary and create performance overhead for my use-case. There is better answer for this question.

Comment: see whether this helps: [How to force Dotnet6 Desktop Winforms App to use appsettings.json instead of Settings.settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74804624/7444103) -- BTW, take a look at my comments on that Q&A, to avoid not-so-subtle mistakes

Comment: @Jimi Yes, the answer you linked to might be the solution. I am going to give it a try. Also to see how reliable it is.

Comment: It turned out that the answer provided in the linked answer is not good for my question. But someone rushed to close the question before I tested it.