# How to access appsettings from Blazor Hybrid in Winforms

Tags: winforms, dependency-injection, blazor, appsettings, blazor-hybrid

I'm trying to setup DI in a Winforms Blazor app. Winforms is used simply a placeholder for the all the Blazor functionality.
I understand the Blazor DI is setup within the form constructor (as per Dan Roth sample app):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         var services = new ServiceCollection();
         services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();
         services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
         blazorWebView1.HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";
         blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
         blazorWebView1.RootComponents.Add<Main>("#app");
     }

 }
```

instead of the Winforms Program.cs. However, some of the services require configuration from appsettings.json, which I would normally do in the program.cs as:

```
 var builder = CreateHostBuilder()
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
         {
             builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
             builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json");
         });

 var host = builder.Build();
```

Similarly, CommectionString also comes from appsettings.

So how do you either access builder.Configuration from the Form (Blazor side)? Or access it as normal in Winforms startup and provide it to the Blazor startup?

```
 services.AddSingleton<ISheetToolConfig>(
     builder.Configuration.GetSection("SheetToolConfig").Get<SheetToolConfig>()
         ?? throw new NullReferenceException("SheetToolConfig"));
```

Comment: You can still create the `ServiceCollection` in Program.cs, you only need to pass the `services` object to the Forms that host a BlazorWebView (so you can assign it to `blazorWebView1.Services`) -- Btw, you may want to see [How to force Dotnet6 Desktop Winforms App to use appsettings.json instead of Settings.settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74804624/7444103). Read the comments

Comment: Thanks Jimi, I've got it working.  I now add services in Program.cs which just create the config classes (connection string etc) from app settings.  These are injected into the Form.  All the Blazor DI classes are now added n the Form constructor. Works a treat. The bit I don't get is you mention creating the service collection in Program.cs & passing the services into the form.  How would it be passed?

Comment: Well, from the code you posted it wasn't clear whether you're using DI to also handle your Forms (i.e., you have a ServiceProvider, a Factory etc.). If you are, the argument is mute. If you don't, you could be running a starting Form as usual (via `Application.Run()`). In this case, you create the `ServiceCollection` in Program.cs and pass the `services` object in the Constructor of each new Form you create (i.e., you have `public Form1() => InitializeComponent(); public Form1(ServiceCollection services) : this() { blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider(); // [...]}`

Comment: That's great Jimi, I appreciate your responses.