# App.config's element values to be used in Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

Is it possible use App.config's value in Connectionstring. Example is mentioned below.

```
<appsettings><add key="UserName" Value="abc" /></appsettings>

<connectionstring><add name="Conn" connectionString="Server=test;   Database=test; Uid=UserName; Pwd=test123;" />
```

So as you can see that I have defined the Username in appsettings and I want to see that into the connection string

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it's impossible.
You can use different App.config files for different configuration (Debug, Release) and set your connection string in them.
Look [here](https://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295497/visual-studio-differentiate-app-config-for-debug-and-release-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format()`.
Just change `Uid=UserName;` to `Uid={0};"`.

`String connectionString = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].Value);`

Comment: This is probably the "best" option for what you are trying to do but that means you HAVE to manipulate the connection string every time and can't simply use it. I would look into a utility to tokenize your app.config so that those values are always the same.