# How to create multiple app.config for different environments where values can be overridden

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config, config-transformation

How can I create multiple app.config for different environments where values can be overridden

For example, I want to have app.Debug.config and app.Release.config where I can change specific values in  like I do on my web projects ([Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx)):

```
<add key="Test" value="Value_For_Test_Environment" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295497/visual-studio-differentiate-app-config-for-debug-and-release-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose I used an extension called ***SlowCheetah***. It brings the transformation to non-web projects. In the market you have the tutorial to use it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms