# Why does publishing a .NET 5 API project removes my app settings in App.config?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .NET 5 API project that I was trying to publish into a local directory. The project has an `App.config` file that contains the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="Config\appSettings.dev.config">
    <!-- Add comment-->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I need the above app.config as we're  migrating from an older .NET Framework application to a new .NET 5 application and we want to keep the XML config files for now. We'll migrate it in the future but for now, we want to keep the config file as is.

When I publish the project however, the App.config transforms into the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" /></startup></configuration>
```

I'm unsure why the comment has dissapeard and the `<appSettings>` element is gone? How do I publish it so the elements are still there?

The file has `Copy always` set in the file property section.

Comment: What are you using to publish your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to get the `app.config` to be published properly and is now available in the `published` directory. I'm not 100% sure how I managed to publish it now but here are some of the things that I changed:

1. Previously the file name was `App.config`. We deleted it and changed it to `app.config`. (This, to my knowledge shouldn't change anything but in case it helps anyone else)
2. We were referencing a lot of .NET 2.0 standard projects which in turn were referencing some .NET 472 projects. This might have caused some sort of weird publishing issues which might have been fixed after the references to .NET 472 were removed.

Throughout all of this, we were creating our packages using dotnet publish and a Release configuration through TeamCity.

The main reason I was so concerned about the `App.Config` not showing appsettings value was that as mentioned above, we needed to use the older XML appsettings configuration as we're updating to .NET 5. We published the project into App Service and wanted to run it in Azure.

It turns out however, that the publishing process copied values from `App.config` into the DLL's config file, e.g. `ManagementApi.dll.config`.
This is the file that's used for configuration when IIS runs the web API in Azure using the `AspNetCoreModuleV2`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your appsettings.json and launchsettings.json are configured accordingly for your development and production profiles.
[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) say that some of the values are not set for production so they probably create a default file which looks like your case if you published in Release format.

If that doesn't work you can also try using xsd:transform with same value like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295497/visual-studio-differentiate-app-config-for-debug-and-release-mode#50373936)